# Solve polynomials in addition in Java?

Tags: java, regex, split, addition, polynomials

I have to solve the polynomials in addition but its really hard for me. How can I do this?

```
poly1 = "2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2";
poly2 = "2x^2 + 6";


//result
2x^3 + 5x^2 + 8
```

Comment: Which part of the task are you stuck on?

Comment: I just want to add them with the use of variables, but its difficult. I tried to use, for loop to split them.

Answer (score 0):

Often a system will just record the coefficients, and store the power by position:

```
double[] poly1 = {2,3,2};
double[] poly2 = {0,2,6};
```

Then to add two polynomials you just add the numbers at each position.

Comment: Is there any method aside to this. I really want to input also the variables.